# PyTorch conv2d doesn't propagate torch.channels_last memory format

Tags: python, pytorch

When I try to use the `torch.nn.conv2d` operator on tensors which have the `channels_last` memory format, then the output does not keep this memory format.

I don't understand why, since `conv2d` is listed in the [PyTorch wiki listing operators with channels last support](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/wiki/Operators-with-Channels-Last-support).

Am I missing something?

Code to reproduce (tested with pytorch 1.6.0 and 1.7.0, on CPU, on Ubuntu 20.04):

```py
import torch
import torch.nn.functional as F

N, C, H, W = 10, 4, 64, 128
out_channels = 2
kernel_size = (3, 3)

memory_format = torch.channels_last

tsr = torch.randn(N, C, H, W).to(memory_format=memory_format)
kernel = torch.randn(out_channels, C, *kernel_size).to(memory_format=memory_format)

conv_out = F.conv2d(tsr, kernel)

print(conv_out.is_contiguous(memory_format=memory_format)) # False
```

Comment: For the record, `conv2d` was effectively added to the list of supported CPU operators as of May 22, 2022 (https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/wiki/Operators-with-Channels-Last-support/_history)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `conv2d` operator is listed under the list of **GPU operators** supporting `channels_last`. This is not true for the CPU version of `conv2d`:

If you switch to `cuda` device, it will return `True`:

```
tsr = torch.randn(N, C, H, W).to('cuda', memory_format=memory_format)
kernel = torch.randn(out_channels, C, *kernel_size).to('cuda', memory_format=memory_format)
conv_out = F.conv2d(tsr, kernel)

>>> conv_out.is_contiguous(memory_format=memory_format)
True
```